# React control flow component with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Control flow component with React that

- renders its `children` when the condition is `true`,
- renders `null` or a fallback if the condition is `false`

### The component

```js
interface Props {
    when: boolean
    fallback?: () => JSX.Element
    children: Children
}

export const Show = ({
    when,
    fallback,
    children
}: Props) => {


    if (!when)
        return <>{fallback?.() || null}</>

    return <>{children}</>
}
```

#### Without the component

if I do not use this component and use a simple binary operator, Typescript works great:

```js
interface Props {
    value: {nested: string} | null
}

const SomeComponent =({value}:Props)=>(
    <div>
        {value && (
            <div>
                {value.nested}

                value is inferred the type "{nested: string}"
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
```

#### With the component

If I use the control flow component the type is not inferred and typescript gives an error:

```js
interface Props {
    value: {nested: string} | null
}

const SomeComponent =({value}:Props)=>(
    <div>
        <Show when={!!value}>
            <div>
                {value?.nested}

                typeof value remains "{nested: string} | null", 
                therefore I need some conditional chaining
            </div>
        </Show>
    </div>
```

**Any idea on how to make type inference work?**

Comment: Set the
interface Props {
    value?: {nested: string} | null
} optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in this way, because the code inside `<Show></Show>` is actually executed before `Show` gets a chance to prevent the `div` from rendering. Think what happens when JSX is transpiled to javascript:

```
React.createElement(
  Show, 
  {when: !!value},
  React.createElement(
    'div',
    {},
    `${value?.nested} typeof value remains "{nested: string} | null", therefore I need some conditional chaining`
  )
)
```

See the problem? If we rewrite it a bit:

```
const textContent = `${value?.nested} typeof value remains "{nested: string} | null", therefore I need some conditional chaining`
React.createElement(
  Show, 
  {when: !!value},
  React.createElement(
    'div',
    {},
    textContent
  )
)
```

These snippets are exactly the same, and in both of them `value?.nested` is evaluated before `Show` even renders. I can't recommend you any good solution here, maybe something like this:

```
interface Props<T> {
    value: T
    fallback?: () => JSX.Element
    children: (value: T) => ReactNode
}

export const CheckExists = <T extends any>({
    value,
    fallback,
    children
}: Props<T>) => {
    if (!value)
        return fallback ? fallback() : null
    return <>{children(value)}</>
}

<CheckExists value={value}>
  {existingValue => (
    <div>{existingValue.nested}</div>
  )}
</CheckExists>
```

But this is different interface and may not be suitable for you

Comment: Thx for your answer, it is now clear why typescript  fails here. Very nice workaround, however when compared to inline binary / ternary operators it has no real advantage... I think I'll just stick to binary/ternary at this point